# What is going on with this question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[Is there a chart that translates old tube symbol to the new tube symbol](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/470485/is-there-a-chart-that-translates-old-tube-symbol-to-the-new-tube-symbol)

I got an answer to this question  i dont know why this question was closed.

This has been my second question thats been shut down even though it has an answer and a upvote.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest problem is that you never defined "the new format" that you were looking for. There is no single standard for such symbols.